# How to handle force close event in ionic app?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, forceclose

I want to close my app when user force close.

Any event arise for force close in ionic application ?

Any plugin for force close event handling in ionic app ?

example:
A common piece of functionality for native mobile applications is the ability to logged out if the user closes the application(force stop/force close).

How can this be achieved for a Cordova / Ionic / PhoneGap ?

Answer (score 2):

Put the following code accordingly to your angular.run configuration, and that's it. You can even add some checks, for example using a boolean value in a Service or a check to the current state to decide if prompt to the user the closing app notice or not.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {
     $ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(function () {
      if(true) { // your check here
         $ionicPopup.confirm({
             title: 'System warning',
             template: 'are you sure you want to exit?'
         }).then(function(res){
             if( res ){
               navigator.app.exitApp();
             }
         })
      }
   })
});
```

[***More...***](http://codepen.io/mircobabini/developer/ionic-change-on-hardware-back-button-pressed-action)